# Correct approach for postDelay method of handler in the constructor

Tags: android, handler, android-handler

I have the following thread with a constructor in my service class.

```
public class communicationDetails extends Thread {
    communicationDetails(final Handler _handler, final Handler conn_handler) throws IOException {
        mhandler = _handler;
        connHandler = conn_handler;
    }
```

In `onCreate` in my service I tried to construct the thread and start it.First handler works fine, I could able to send messages. Since I want to post a message with delay, in the second handler I am trying to use postDelay method. This is where the problem comes in.

```
    try {
        communication_Details = new communicationDetails(
                // works fine
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
                    @Override
                    public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
                        // sending messages
                    }
                }, 

                //this throws an error
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                      // call a method
                    }
                }, 2000));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    communication_Details.start();
```

I get following error. What stupid mistake am I doing here ? or is it completely wrong approach.

`error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to Handler`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error : `incompatible types` is because :-

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable) --> returns boolean
```

while the constructor requires object of type `android.os.Handler`

So you are *basically* passing `boolean` instead of an instance of `Handler`

For more info checkout `android.os.Handler`. **( cmd + click ) on Handler**

Comment: thanks for your comment. Should I declare `type boolean in the constructor` ? How else could I use postDelay method ?

Comment: you can use the post delay method inside `communicationDetails` class . Just pass the handler object to the constructor.. and call the postDelayed in the constructor itself ! or you can change the parameter to boolean. !

Comment: Thanks man. I changed the type to boolean. It worked, fine :)